# file:/// to http:// communication via IFrame

Tags: html, iframe, cdc

Maybe some of you could have ran into the same problem i did.
Imagine you have a file on your machine: file:///c:\test.html

And you have an IFrame inside of this file. You need to indicate whether the IFrame contents are loaded or no.

Bacically, what we have here:
1. location, href, or any other property is inaccessible from file:/// to http:///, or backwards.
2. you can't fire event from the browser window in iframe, or in opposite direction, unfortunately.

Does this problem have a solution?
P.S.: that's not a hack. it's a real problem. making some interaction from local machine with website integration.

UPD: I kinda figure out why it's forbidden. ANY interaction with local files should be forbidden from the web page. It's kinda cool, i do agree. But isn't a # hashtag something that can't harm anyone? :(

Comment: "Cross Site Scripting" is the name of the problem you are having.  This is disabled as part of a security feature in the browser.

Comment: How much control do you have over the local machine?

Comment: 100% bloody control :)
@david, this is not Cross Site Scripting, telling you again. it's working with the same exact code from http://localhost/test.html to http://mydomain.com/myPage.html 
i suppose (not sure thou) it's a browser protection of local files.

Comment: Just to be annoying, I'll say that if you have full control of the local machine, I suspect that pointing the user's browser to a local file may not be the right approach.  What is it you're actually trying to accomplish on that page?

Comment: i acknowledge this, Jeremy. i know that it's not a right approach. i didn't know it before. reading Firefox and IE specifications did help a lot. anyways, thank you so much for helping out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find some of these techniques useful:  http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

**Edit**: Per comments below, these techniques don't seem to work when accessing `file:///c:\<path>\test.html`, whereas they do when accessing `http://localhost/test.html`.

I think that's because the `file` protocol is even more restricted by the browser than the `http` protocol.  The [MSDN page on the file protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> Internet Explorer 6 Service Pack 1 (SP1) no longer allows browsing a
>   local machine from the Internet zone. For instance, if an Internet site
>   contains a link to a local file, Internet Explorer 6 SP1 displays a
>   blank page when a user clicks on the link. Previous versions of Windows
>   Internet Explorer followed the link to the local file.

Whatever technique you were using to get some cross-domain communication was probably blocked by the browser because you were using the `file` protocol.

Comment: yup, red it about an hour ago and googled the whole universe, honestly. i wouldn't post the question unless i'd be sure that i'm without any clue... thank you thou!

Comment: Yeah, those techniques weren't very pretty, were they.

Comment: yup, they sure are...
BUT. it all works from http://localhost/test.html
but no success from file:///c:\<path>\test.html

Comment: Well, can you toss a mini web server on their machine?

Comment: not a problem, i can do it in seconds. for now it's the question of principle. i just want to freaking understand why on earth it's impossible :) when i do, i will move on :) just wanna make sure i'm right)

Comment: My guess is that there are some special rules regarding the file: protocol.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: i will do as well whenever i have more info