# vimeo froogaloop API only works when website is hosted?

Tags: javascript, iframe, localhost, vimeo, froogaloop

I came across Drew Baker's froogaloop API example page:
http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html

I view and copy the exact source code on a html 
but when I test it locally, the API does not work, 
vimeo player does not play, nor alert the messages

it only works when I host the html locally with MAMP 
why is this ????

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're adding the `&api=1` string to the video?

I don't have a Froogaloop demo handy, but I did make a demo that doesn't use Froogaloop: [check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/GxwEX/).

Comment: hey man thanks for the reply, I do have api=1 ... :s ... really love the demo! helps heaps ! the vimeo api doc is so poor, it's really hard to get  my head around how it exactly works :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have asked first, but the demo I shared only works on an iframe based player.. it basically uses the iframes "postMessage" to pass a json string between the parent and the iframe. This functionality isn't available is IE8 and older though. So if you need to play a video in an older browser, use the embed player like in the link you shared.

Comment: thanks a lot ! starting getting an idea how it works, I think I will only be using the iframe embed player so that's not a problem, cheers ! ....
still has no idea why it needs to be hosted to function properly ... I mirror your example to a html file and test it locally .... it only works when I place the javascript at the bottom of the body ... but when I place javascript at the bottom for my example, nothing changed .... this is so weird : (

Comment: OH duh! I see what you're asking now... Yeah, the problem is due to browser security restrictions between local files and the internet. Check out this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1568653/145346)

Comment: I know this is old, but +1 for the fiddled demo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Froogaloop doesn't work on local urls with `file://`.  You'll need to make your HTML available via `http`. You could use [the node.js `http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to do this easily.

Install from npm:

```
$ npm install http-server -g
```

From the directory you'd like to serve:

```
$ http-server
```

Many other options exist including MAMP, Dropbox's public folder or [Python's SimpleHTTPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-simplehttpserver)