# What is a faster alternative to Python's http.server (or SimpleHTTPServer)?

Tags: command-line, httpserver, command-line-tool, simplehttpserver

Python's [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) (or SimpleHTTPServer for Python 2) is a great way of serve the contents of the current directory from the command line:

```
python -m http.server
```

However, as far as web servers go, it's very slooooow...

It behaves as though it's single threaded, and occasionally causes timeout errors when loading JavaScript AMD modules using RequireJS. It can take five to ten seconds to load a simple page with no images.

What's a faster alternative that is just as convenient?

Comment: This thread just restored my sanity.  I had been using SimpleHTTPServer and getting random errors with RequireJS that were driving me nuts!  node's http-server is working like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: I've had the same. The Python Simple Server can be so slow that RequireJS times out. Node's is way faster, mostly I think because it can handle requests in parallel.

Comment: For portable HTTP servers in windows, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/595466/198348

Comment: @ChrisF, I have edited the question according to [this guideline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/24874) to more grammatically reflect the fact that this _is_ actually an answerable question. I have explained the problem I faced (namely, timeouts and wasted time), and I couldn't list what I had done to address the problem because I didn't know of any alternatives. I don't think this question fits the "What's your favourite ___" shape, as the criteria are clearly defined. Different visitors may find different answers more useful, and answers may not suit the criteria given.

Comment: Love how SO has a habit of closing people's favourite questions…

Comment: This question is not only useful, it also does not match the description for which it is being closed.  At least the research has already been done...

Comment: Another option, if you want to serve up a git repo, is [`git instaweb`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-instaweb).

Comment: I came here, then I realised that as I'm developing in ReactJS I don't actually need a local server to code

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功, this question has already been closed and reopened...

Answer (score 425, accepted):

[http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server) for node.js is very convenient, and is a lot faster than Python's SimpleHTTPServer. This is primarily because it uses asynchronous IO for concurrent handling of requests, instead of serialising requests.

#### Installation

Install node.js if you haven't already. Then use the node package manager (`npm`) to install the package, using the `-g` option to install globally.  If you're on Windows you'll need a prompt with administrator permissions, and on Linux/OSX you'll want to `sudo` the command:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

This will download any required dependencies and install `http-server`.

#### Use

Now, from any directory, you can type:

```
http-server [path] [options]
```

Path is optional, defaulting to `./public` if it exists, otherwise `./`.

Options are [defaults]:

- `-p` The port number to listen on [8080]
- `-a` The host address to bind to [localhost]
- `-i` Display directory index pages [True]
- `-s` or `--silent` Silent mode won't log to the console
- `-h` or `--help` Displays help message and exits

So to serve the current directory on port 8000, type:

```
http-server -p 8000
```

Comment: This is awesome!! Thank you for pointing it out. It's great for testing streaming audio/video which is something the python server doesn't seem to handle well at all.

Comment: @gman, I had a similar experience when I discovered it. I haven't used the Python server since.

Comment: Is there any option to have the server log output, to see if a file is not found e.g. 404 ?

Comment: @poseid, I'm not sure. Perhaps open an issue on the project itself, or fork it and add logging.

Comment: This is great for testing sites on iOS that load large numbers of files. SimpleHTTPServer was not fast enough and caused timeout on Safari. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. Installed it and then when I ran the command 'http-server' it returned with '-bash: http-server: command not found'.

Comment: @Salmonface, did you definitely use the `-g` option, and did you make sure that no errors were printed during the installation? That error just means it cannot be found after the install, which seems unlikely if things went well. What platform are you on? Run a find command across your drive to find a file with name `http-server`. I've used this successfully on a few different Linux distros and Windows versions.

Comment: @DrewNoakes, there didn't seem to be any errors. I'm running OSX v10.9.1. What's strange is that I can find it and uninstall it with npm...

Comment: @Phy6, I rolled back your edit because the problem you are seeing in Windows means it was not installed correctly. I have used this on Windows many times. Are you sure you're typing `http-server` and not `node http-server`? The former is correct. Can't test as I'm on Linux now.

Comment: When I access some html file through this server, the browser tries to download it (!?).. curl reports the content-type as "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8" ... how to make it work?

Comment: @DavidKrmpotic, I haven't seen that behaviour before. Are your HTML files truly UTF-8, or are there some stray bytes in there. I don't know whether `http-server` inspects the contents to determine MIME type. I would suspect it just goes off the file extension. What extension are you using? Probably worth opening an issue on [the http-server project](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server). [This](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server/issues/35) may be relevant.

Comment: Actually I think I made a mistake... tried to read something.haml instead of .html.. :) Now it works!

Comment: I just want to confirm that using this solution improved my page load time from 20s to 2s!

Comment: Well, at first it was an improvement over the python SimpleHTTPServer until I ran out of memory. http-server consumes a huge amount of memory for large files. The myserver.go proposal is fast an consumes just about 2 MB instead of 5 GB Memory, before starting to swap and getting really slow.

Comment: Even simpler than all of the above consider [devd](https://github.com/cortesi/devd)

Comment: Does this not support serving on both IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: Why is this faster than Python's?

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功, good question. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I had issues serving media files with this after a little bit of time running the server.

Comment: So as of Nov 2019 it looks as though http-server has been broken for windows users for several months. Many of its dependencies are way out of date. One of them, ecstatic, is now abandoned so it's not clear when or if it will be fixed. I looked into fixing myself but it's also not clear if the devs will take PRs. So, I wrote my own [replacement](https://github.com/greggman/servez-cli).

Comment: Use webfs instead.

Answer (score 117):

I recommend: **Twisted** (http://twistedmatrix.com)

> an event-driven networking engine written in Python and licensed under the open source  MIT license.

It's cross-platform and was preinstalled on OS X 10.5 to 10.12. Amongst other things you can start up a simple web server in the current directory with:

```
twistd -no web --path=.
```

#### Details

Explanation of Options (see `twistd --help` for more):

```
-n, --nodaemon       don't daemonize, don't use default umask of 0077
-o, --no_save        do not save state on shutdown
```

"web" is a Command that runs a simple web server on top of the Twisted async engine. It also accepts command line options (after the "web" command - see `twistd web --help` for more):

```
  --path=             <path> is either a specific file or a directory to be
                      set as the root of the web server. Use this if you
                      have a directory full of HTML, cgi, php3, epy, or rpy
                      files or any other files that you want to be served up
                      raw.
```

There are also a bunch of other commands such as:

```
conch            A Conch SSH service.
dns              A domain name server.
ftp              An FTP server.
inetd            An inetd(8) replacement.
mail             An email service
... etc
```

#### Installation

Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python-twisted-web (or python-twisted for the full engine)
```

Mac OS-X (comes preinstalled on 10.5 - 10.12, or is available in MacPorts and through Pip)

```
sudo port install py-twisted
```

Windows

```
installer available for download at http://twistedmatrix.com/
```

#### HTTPS

Twisted can also utilise security certificates to encrypt the connection. Use this with your existing `--path` and `--port` (for plain HTTP) options.

```
twistd -no web -c cert.pem -k privkey.pem --https=4433
```

Comment: Unless you already have node.js set up, I found this to be the most convenient. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: On Ubuntu, you have to `sudo apt-get install python-twisted-web` first. (Thanks for this answer, it's very convenient!)

Comment: One special advantage of twisted one line server, it support resumable downloads (byte range support), and that is a must have feature when you are downloading large files.

Comment: using node did not stream video/audio properly for me, using twistd works great though!

Comment: You can configure ports and get other options using `twistd --help` and `twistd web --help`. Took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: I honestly can't figure this out.  I've installed Python 2.7.  I installed twisted.  The UI was kind of screwy (for both, with like, words flying off the dialogs and stuff, go figure, python can't handle 125% DPI... but where was I?) -- right -- the dialog was screwy, I think it was asking me where python was installed, in a strange way.  I told it.  and ... was able to proceed.  I seriously have no idea where this thing installed itself.  There is no file matching the pattern `*twistd*.*` anywhere on any of my hard drives after installing twisted.  Very disappointed.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I would suggest asking a new question rather than posting a comment. More likely to get an answer that way

Comment: I like this because I can expect it to work out of the box on any Mac.

It also has help unlike SimpleHTTPServer, so I could figure out how to make it serve from a specific folder and thru a specific port:

`twistd -no web -p 3003 --path=resources/public/`

Comment: excellent and clear answer and good info about installing it on Ubuntu. Also you can use `-p 80` for setting port number with `sudo` (in Ubuntu run: `sudo twistd -no web -p 80`)

Comment: This works great except that trying to start multiple is messy. You have to specify a `--pidfile` and `--logfile` to avoid clashes. Would be great if the authors could fix this. `SimpleHTTPServer` doesn't require this.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat From memory it logs to stdout by default so you shouldn't need to customise that. Pidfile is created in the current directory by default also so as long as you're starting the server in separate folders you should be fine. However, the pidfile is not required when not forking to the background so it can be disabled with `pidfile=` (leaving the right side empty disables pidfile)

Comment: How twistd can live reload when the file changes?

Comment: I'm on macOS 10.13, this doesn't seem to be pre-installed anymore

Comment: If you're using conda, `conda install twisted`

Answer (score 36):

[[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) 1.0 includes a [http server](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) & [util for serving files](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) with a few lines of code.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"; "log"; "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Serving files in the current directory on port 8080")
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Run this source using `go run myserver.go` or to build an executable `go build myserver.go`

Comment: Great answer. This runs faster than SimpleHTTPServer and nodejs solution. :) Is there any way I can add username and password to the download?

Answer (score 23):

Try [webfs](http://linux.bytesex.org/misc/webfs.html), it's tiny and doesn't depend on having a platform like node.js or python installed.

Comment: looks like you have to compile it?  Didn't see any binaries for download.

Comment: yes, unless your distro has it. Debian and Ubuntu have it: `apt-get install webfs`

Comment: I did a `brew install webfs` on my Mac which resulted in `  /usr/local/Cellar/webfs/1.21: 5 files, 96K, built in 15 seconds`. Afterwards I could just say `webfsd -F -p 3003 -r resources/public/ -f index.html` to achieve the same as `twistd -no web -p 3003 --path=resources/public/`. It's a bit wordy so not obvious to remember  but good to know as an alternative to twistd or SimpleHTTPServer.

Comment: Much better than the other solutions. It's very small, very fast and provided as an OS package.
It also supports SSL and can run as a system daemon.

Answer (score 16):

If you use Mercurial, you can use the built in HTTP server. In the folder you wish to serve up:

```
hg serve
```

From [the docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/hgserve):

```
export the repository via HTTP

    Start a local HTTP repository browser and pull server.

    By default, the server logs accesses to stdout and errors to
    stderr. Use the "-A" and "-E" options to log to files.

options:

 -A --accesslog       name of access log file to write to
 -d --daemon          run server in background
    --daemon-pipefds  used internally by daemon mode
 -E --errorlog        name of error log file to write to
 -p --port            port to listen on (default: 8000)
 -a --address         address to listen on (default: all interfaces)
    --prefix          prefix path to serve from (default: server root)
 -n --name            name to show in web pages (default: working dir)
    --webdir-conf     name of the webdir config file (serve more than one repo)
    --pid-file        name of file to write process ID to
    --stdio           for remote clients
 -t --templates       web templates to use
    --style           template style to use
 -6 --ipv6            use IPv6 in addition to IPv4
    --certificate     SSL certificate file

use "hg -v help serve" to show global options
```

Answer (score 12):

[Here's another. It's a Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)

Once installed you can run it by creating a new tab in Chrome and clicking the *apps* button near the top left

It has a simple gui. Click choose folder, then click the `http://127.0.0.1:8887` link

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AK6swHiPtew

Answer (score 10):

I found `python -m http.server` unreliable—some responses would take seconds.

Now I use a server called Ran https://github.com/m3ng9i/ran

> Ran: a simple static web server written in Go

Answer (score 9):

Also consider [devd](https://github.com/cortesi/devd) a small webserver written in go. Binaries for many platforms are available [here](https://github.com/cortesi/devd/releases/tag/v0.5).

```
devd -ol path/to/files/to/serve
```

It's small, fast, and provides some interesting optional features like live-reloading when your files change.

Answer (score 6):

If you have PHP installed you could use the builtin server.

```
php -S 0:8080
```

Comment: Much better solution than Python/Node.

Comment: For me, `php -S localhost:8080`

Answer (score 4):

give polpetta a try ...

```
npm install -g polpetta
```

then you can

```
polpetta ~/folder
```

and you are ready to go :-)

Comment: Can you expand on *why* we should give [polpetta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polpetta) a try?

Answer (score 3):

Using Servez as a server

1. Download [Servez](https://greggman.github.io/servez/)
2. Install It, Run it
3. Choose the folder to serve
4. Pick "Start"
5. Go to `http://localhost:8080` or pick "Launch Browser"

[image: servez]

Note: I threw this together because Web Server for Chrome is going away since [Chrome is removing support for apps](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) and because I support art students who have zero experience with the command line

Comment: I am voting up for running WebGL examples

Answer (score 2):

Yet another node based simple command line server

https://github.com/greggman/servez-cli

Written partly in response to http-server having issues, particularly on windows.

### installation

[Install node.js](https://nodejs.org) then

```
npm install -g servez
```

### usage

```
servez [options] [path]
```

With no path it serves the current folder.

By default it serves `index.html` for folder paths if it exists. It serves a directory listing for folders otherwise. It also serves CORS headers. You can optionally turn on basic authentication with `--username=somename --password=somepass` and you can serve https.

Answer (score 1):

I like [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server). It is fast and has a nice live reload feature, which is very convenient during developpement.

Usage is very simple:

```
cd ~/Sites/
live-server
```

By default it creates a server with IP 127.0.0.1 and port 8080.

http://127.0.0.1:8080/

If port 8080 is not free, it uses another port:

http://127.0.0.1:52749/

http://127.0.0.1:52858/

If you need to see the web server on other machines in your local network, you can check what is your IP and use:

```
live-server --host=192.168.1.121
```

And here is a script that automatically grab the IP address of the default interface. **It works on macOS only**.

If you put it in `.bash_profile`, the `live-server` command will automatically launch the server with the correct IP.

```
# **
# Get IP address of default interface
# *
function getIPofDefaultInterface()
{
    local  __resultvar=$1

    # Get default route interface
    if=$(route -n get 0.0.0.0 2>/dev/null | awk '/interface: / {print $2}')
    if [ -n "$if" ]; then
            # Get IP of the default route interface
            local __IP=$( ipconfig getifaddr $if )
            eval $__resultvar="'$__IP'"
    else
        # Echo "No default route found"
        eval $__resultvar="'0.0.0.0'"
    fi
}

alias getIP='getIPofDefaultInterface IP; echo $IP'

# **
# live-server
# https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server
# *
alias live-server='getIPofDefaultInterface IP && live-server --host=$IP'
```

Answer (score 1):

### miniserve

[miniserve](https://github.com/svenstaro/miniserve)

- cross platform
- single executable file
- lightweight ( < 2MB for Windows / Linux x86 )

```bash
miniserve . --index index.html
```

### Vercel `serve` (node.js)

If **node.js** is installed, I recommended [vercel serve](https://github.com/vercel/serve)

```bash
# for node.js >= v14
npm install --global serve

# for node.js <= v13
npm install --global serve@13
```

```bash
serve
```

### `http-server` (node.js)

[http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server) latest version does not work ( see [issue](https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/634) ), but v13 works

```
npm install --global http-server@13
http-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [filebrowser](https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser) for the past couple of years and it is the best alternative I have found.

Features I love about it:

- Cross-platform: It supports Linux, MacOs and Windows [(+)](https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser/releases/tag/v2.22.3). It also supports docker [(+)](https://hub.docker.com/r/filebrowser/filebrowser).
- Downloading stuff is a breeze. It can automatically convert a folder into `zip`, `tar.gz` and etc. for transferring folders.
- You can file or folder access to every use.

[image]

Comment: Does this serve up files directly over http in a way that can be used by web developers? It looks to be only a file browser.

Comment: Yes, you can access it via REST API. See [here](https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser/issues/1079) and [here](https://github.com/filebrowser/docs/issues/1).