# WebGL Inspector Extension Does Not Appear in Chrome for file:// urls?

Tags: html, webgl, three.js

My steps (these are the ones described in the docs), under Win 7:

1. Downloaded/unpacked the zip file
2. using cygwin, ran the buildextensions.sh file, which created the lib and extensions dirs
3. opened Chrome
4. installed the webgl extension via the chrome store
   (various repeats of closing/relaunched chrome along the way from here on, with little help)
5. chrome setup->extnesions, make sure webgl is enabled
6. turn on developer mode, "load unpacked extension...." selecting the (created) extensions/chrome directory (in this case, C:\Users\kbjorke\Documents\benvanik-WebGL-Inspector-6108bee\benvanik-WebGL-Inspector-6108bee\core\extensions ) and allow "file://" url's
7. ??? no amount of relaod/update/restart seems to cause the GL logo to appear among the extensions buttons at upper right -- even when I load webgl-intensive pages, UNLESS I first load a webgl page from some NON-file:// page -- if I open another tab with an http:// webgl page, I see the red "GL" indicator TWICE in that address bar, but they both lead to the http:// page, not my file://   !

How can I get at my own page, short of pushing it to an external server?

Comment: For questions about the extension, you'd better contact the developer of [WebGL Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webgl-inspector/ogkcjmbhnfmlnielkjhedpcjomeaghda/details).

Comment: yes, that will be the next step -- github there has been verrrrry quiet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a local server. Just open a command prompt, cd to your webpages and then type

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then go to

```
http://localhost:8000
```

I don't think extensions are allowed to run on file:: urls because then an extension could read your hard drive.

If you are doing video or audio then [try this node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/faster-alternative-to-pythons-simplehttpserver).

Comment: Thanks, I got the same answer from the extension author about an hour later :)

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded WebGL Inspector 1.13, and it has a setting (under Settings>Extensions>WebGL Inspector) that reads "Allow access to file URLs". Does what it sounds like - all set!