# WebGL local textures and cross-domain

Tags: cross-domain, three.js, webgl

I wrote a webgl program which works well with a local server, and now, I would like to run it locally.
 But I had errors and after some researches, I found that it's a cross domain issue in loading textures.

```
function loadTexture( path ) {
    var texture = new THREE.Texture( texture_placeholder );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: true} );

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {

        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        material.map.image = this;

       render();
   };
   texture.deallocate();
   renderer3D.deallocateTexture( texture );

   return material;
 }
```

I tried several solutions :

github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1305

github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/944

gist.github.com/ekeneijeoma/1186920

github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally (the 1.Change security for local files in a browser (access page as file:///example))

I precise that I have no problem on Firefox, it works without changing anything.
The only solution which works on Chrome is to launch it with --allow-file-access-from-files.
And on IE, I don't know how to solve it, I enabled in the browser security options "Access data sources across domains" and "Navigate sub-frames across different domains" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee797612(v=cs.20).aspx) but nothing. I use IEWebGL and I have noticed that on http://iewebgl.com/, "IEWebGL v1.0 Released" section, it's written "- Secure (no local content loading, no cross-domain textures)". So maybe it can't be solved on IE due to IEWebGL !?

So what would be the solution for IE, if there is one? And is there a way to solve the problem by changing the code, without lauching a local server or Chrome with special option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

this question has been asked and answered at least 6 other times and is even answered in the three.js wiki.

The short of it is you need to run a local server. Open a terminal/shell/command prompt and type

```
cd <path/to/files>
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then in your browser go to

```
http://localhost:8000
```

Why is that not an option? It's simple and it solves the problem. It also doesn't leave your browser open to getting owned.

Here's [several simple servers you could use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer.

Indeed, it has already been asked and solved, I saw the solutions and it works well with a local server, and I totally agree with about security.

I was asking that because, firstly, it works without any server on Firefox and Safari, and on Google with --allow..., so if it was possible on IE, it would have been good. And secondly, because I wanted a very simple program which works quickly without having to install python or something else for a server,...

In fact, it's for an offline application (I know it's weird for a web based application but it's not my choice :) ). Anyway, it works for Firefox, Chrome and Safari so, too bad for IE.

Thanks!

Comment: This section is for answers, not replies; you should add it as a comment to the other answer, instead. If you are happy with the other answer, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark.