# use html5 video (localhost) with SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, html, simplehttpserver

I use [google io slide deck](https://code.google.com/p/io-2012-slides/), and works fine until I added a link to a video. I have a 11MB video file, which I included in the slide as

```
<video src="video/out/report.mp4"  height="600" controls>
```

When run the server (`server.sh` - `$open http://localhost:$port/index.html && python -m SimpleHTTPServer $port;`), it stucks where the video.

```
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [11/Mar/2013 07:56:18] "GET /images/task.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [11/Mar/2013 07:56:18] "GET /images/receive/external.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [11/Mar/2013 07:56:18] "GET /video/out/report.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

there is no activity after the last line. But when open the index.html ***directly*** (without a webserver, just double click the file and open in browser), ***the video loads***.

Anything wrong with the video tag url that it prevents loading when run with webserver?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be that SimpleHTTPServer is serving the file with the wrong media type.  you should be able to tell using the developer tools in your browser, or with `curl -vs http://localhost:8000/video/out/report.mp4 > /dev/null`

Comment: +1 thanks @TokenMacGuy. I think it better solved by using node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw require.js error aswell, which lead to [What is a faster alternative to Python's http.server (or SimpleHTTPServer)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/faster-alternative-to-pythons-simplehttpserver)

Using node.js server instead worked great.