# Three.JS animation not showing on Chrome v61 Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, three.js

I've been following a few introductory tutorials to `three.js` and can't get past seeing a red background I add in the CSS but none of the `three.js` that I built on my own in `Atom` on `Chrome` (Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)), `Mac OS X` (macOS Sierra, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB). When I download the exact same code from the tutorial and run it `Downloads>threes_js_basic>index.html` I can see the expected output. But when I copy/paste and run it on a local server  all I see is the red background that I added in the `CSS`.

I tried running this through a local server after following as suggested in this [Google-chrome can't locally view my webGL Three.js webpages in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624863/google-chrome-cant-locally-view-my-webgl-three-js-webpages-in-ubuntu) but I haven't had any luck. When I `View Page Source` in `Chrome` the code including the `three.js` is clearly visible.

I've enabled `WebGL` and even installed an extension that allows cross-origin resource sharing.

The code below is a direct copy from the tutorial - I downloaded the source and copy/pasted into Atom. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biZgx45Mzqo&t=71s

```
<html>
<head>
<title>threejs - basic</title>
<style>
    body{
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    canvas{
        background: red;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<script src="three.js"></script>
<script>

    //RENDERER
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('myCanvas'), antialias: true});
    renderer.setClearColor(0x00ff00);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    //CAMERA
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
    // var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / -2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / -2, 0.1, 3000);

    //SCENE
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    //LIGHTS
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(light);

    var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(light1);

    //OBJECT
    var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xF3FFE2});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(0, 0, -1000);

    scene.add(mesh);


    //RENDER LOOP
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    function render() {
        mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: no errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error related to not including this in `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
```

I hadn't come by this link in other tutorials so it was either downloaded prior to recording or, as I'm still new to three.js and likely to be missing more technical answers, it was available elsewhere within the tutorial and I missed it.

Thanks to @2pha for prompting me to check console - I wasn't aware I could do that in Chrome. Cheers!