# How to allow-file-access-from-files in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I am using Chrome to test some of my WebGL texture programs. According to the book 'WebGL Programming Guide', if I need to access files from my local disk, I should add the option --allow-file-access-from-files to Chrome.

How do I do that?

Comment: Modify the shortcut used to start it. I usually find it's better to set up a small local web server though (plenty of e.g. python scripts out there) for more flexibility, and it's much closer to 'reality' in many ways.

Comment: I don't get it. When I tried to add the option after chrome.exe, it said the file is not valid.

Comment: Try quotes, or run from the command line...make sure the additional option is in the 'arguments' field.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is [**DON'T**](https://games.greggman.com/game/dont-disable-web-security/)

Open up a shell/terminal/command line and type

```
cd path/to/htmlfiles
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then in your browser to go

```
http://localhost:8000
```

If you find it's too slow [consider this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/faster-alternative-to-pythons-simplehttpserver)

The reason you don't want to allow file access is allowing it can be used to steal data from your machine. For example, you go to a site and download some webpage. You then view that page locally. With file access on that locally run page can now access all your files AND upload them to a server.

Comment: I have not been using python. Must I somehow install python in my local computer first? I know enabling local file access opens a security loophole, but I just want to enable it for a short time and disable it later.