# httpRequest.status code 0 when attempting to retrieve array from local JSON file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest, local

I'm trying to retrieve an array from a JSON file named questions.json (that is in the same folder as the JavaScript file). To overcome the same origin policy, I've allowed XMLHttpRequest to access local files using the Chrome `--allow-file-access-from-files` switch.

I've looked up other questions related to this, but I'm still not sure why my request fails. Is the failure related to my AJAX call to localhost? Is what I am doing a valid HTTP request? Did I not overcome the same origin policy?

```
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(httpRequest.status);
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var allQuestions = httpRequest.responseText 
        } else {
            console.log('There was a problem with the request.')
        }
    } else {
        console.log('The request is still not ready.')
    }
}  

httpRequest.open('GET', 'questions.json', true);
httpRequest.send(null);
```

My console shows that the request is still not ready (3 times), that XHR has finished loading, that the `httpRequest.status` is 0, then that there was a problem with the request.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Edited to add what error I am seeing

Comment: What is `Quiz interactivity.js` ?

Comment: My JavaScript file that contains the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: is questions.json in the same folder as the file executing this code?

Comment: I guess you just are being "confused" over your own console.logs.  There will always be `onreadystatechange`'s even if the file not is finished loading - if you make a `console.log(allQuestions)` you will see that the request eventually actually successes.

Comment: @davidkonrad: After the file finishes loading (when `httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE`), the flow of control jumps to the `else` statement and outputs that there was a problem with the request. I tried putting a `console.log(allQuestions)` on the line after `var allQuestions`, but there is no output.

Comment: @BriennaHerold - I copied and tried out your code and it worked right away -  despite 3 times "_The request is still not ready_" and a `200` in the console, `questions.json` is sucessfully loaded into `allQuestions`.

Comment: Hmm. Did you use a server or the same switch as I did? @davidkonrad

Comment: tried ther code in www on a apache server using chrome - actually I have never heard about that switch before, and something tells me that it is obsolete and should be avoided -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826544/chrome-allow-file-access-from-files-no-longer-working-was-using-to-see-webgl-th