# Run angular 7 routing-based app as `file://` (without server)

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have angular app that is **based on routing**, what I want is to bundle it into WebView application as html file so it will be accessible by `~/app_path/index.html`

I successfully built it with `ng build --prod --output-path ./../ng-build` and it loads fine in browser.

The problem is if I use router module I will get `Unhandled Navigation Error` warning and routes just don't work.

I tried to use hashes with `useHash`

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
```

and expected it might work with routes e.g.

```
`~/app_path/index.html#settings`
`~/app_path/index.html#profile`
`~/app_path/index.html#details`
```

but it doesn't help - router crashes immediately after app launch

[image]

Is there any solution or workaround to achieve routing in this `file://` mode? Or maybe another architecture approach to use in the app here instead of routing.

Comment: what about calling a route like : ``~/app_path/index.html/#/settings`?

Comment: I expected it should work but the app crashes on the load. just found a solution - `useHash` should be paired with absolute filesystem path that can be taken from location as per this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13948#issuecomment-302727428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13948#issuecomment-302727428) setting `<base>` href attr to absolute path helps to solve routing issue

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

so the base element will look like this

```
<base href="file:///Users/guest/build/index.html">
```

routing demo:

[image]