# SecurityError for same-origin image texImage2D

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, textures, webgl

I am currently learning WebGL.  In a call to texImage2D, which is called when a texture has finished loading, I get the following `SecurityError`:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at /path/to/texure.png may not be loaded.
```

However, the file is on the same domain, in fact it is in the same directory as the html file requesting it.

Here is the file layout:

```
> js
|-> script.js
|-> glUtils.js
|-> sylvester.js
> texture.png
> index.html
```

And when I look in the F12 console's resource list, the image `texture.png` is there, fully loaded, and it is 256 x 256.  Why does it think I am requesting from another domain?

Comment: Are you working from `file://` URLs?  They're not treated as being in the same domain as each other for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, I am.  Is there any way I can do this from my local site?

Comment: If you serve up the stuff from a local webserver it'll work, because the browser *will* see those as being from the same domain. Chrome used to have an command-line option to allow it: `--allow-file-access-from-files` but I don't know if it still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is that you must be on a local webserver, because file:/// domain requests will not be granted.  (Information given by Pointy:

> If you serve up the stuff from a local webserver it'll work, because the browser will see those as being from the same domain. Chrome used to have an command-line option to allow it: --allow-file-access-from-files but I don't know if it still works

Answer (score 3):

You're probably getting the error because you're using a `file://` based URL.

The solution is to use a simple web server. Open a terminal and type

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

then go to `http://localhost:8000` (install python if you're on Windows) or use [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-simplehttpserver/12905427#12905427) or possibly even better use [devd](https://github.com/cortesi/devd)

Do NOT use `--allow-file-access-from-files`. This opens your machine to getting hacked through the browser. That would be like turning off your firewall or your virus scanner.

Comment: Thanks! I got here from the learningwebgl.com blog lesson 05 on textures. Having only static local files this error cropped up and the `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` got it up and running for me. Cheers!!