# Web server capable of directory index with parallel requests handling and white spaces filenames support

Tags: python, web-services, web

I was searching for simple web server that is capable to directory index. In the past I was using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` drawback of this is solution is that it only can serve one request at time. Then I inspired by following question [What is a faster alternative to Python's SimpleHTTPServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-simplehttpserver) and I've tried node.js and twisted. Those two solved the problem with processing one request at time but another problem here is that both node.js and twisted are not able to process files which contains spaces (python solution worked). How to have both parallel requests handling and support for white spaces in filenames?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not considering a "real" web-server like apache, nginx or lighttpd?

Comment: Probably not, but I just want something little, fast and easy to configure. It should serve files for VLC player. Now it runs on my PC but probably one nice day it will run on raspberry PI (which I do not have yet). Are those two requests that I have something special for lightweight web servers?

Comment: From my own experience: getting any of those webservers running on a pi is nothing special - there are standard linux packages available for all of them. I think at least nginx & lighttpd can also be called lightweight...

Comment: Does both lighthttpd and nginx suits for my needs?