# Unity3D - Let user load image for webgl

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

My code strangely isn't loading the user images from local hard drive to the gameObject called "planeLogo". The file with the function ImageUploaderCaptureClick() is called ImageUploader1.jslib and resides in the plugins/WebGl folder.

Here's the script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class LoadImage : MonoBehaviour
{


    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void ImageUploaderCaptureClick();
    private Texture2D displayedTexture;

    IEnumerator LoadTexture(string url)
    {
        WWW image = new WWW(url);
        yield return image;
        image.LoadImageIntoTexture(displayedTexture);
    }

    void FileSelected(string url)
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadTexture(url));
    }

    public void OnButtonPointerDown()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        string path = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Open image", "", "jpg,png,bmp");
        if (!System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            FileSelected("file:///" + path);
#else
        ImageUploaderCaptureClick ();
#endif
    }

    void Start()
    {
        displayedTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        GameObject.Find("PlaneLogo").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = displayedTexture;
        GameObject.Find("PlaneLogo").GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

And here's how I deal with the events.

[image]

I've tried everything I know and the project keeps working inside Unity but does not when it's compiled as html(webgl).

Comment: Run a simple web server. It will take you just a few seconds to setup. [How about this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)? or [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-simplehttpserver/)

Answer (score 0):

Unity WebGL does not have access to your file system

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-debugging.html

You'll have to fetch your image from a server. It's ghetto but the only way I could see it happening is if you set something up where the server fetches the image locally and relays it to your WebGL game.

Answer (score 0):

hey bro you should try to this code it's work perfectly
here my code:

```
string str_Parthname = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/SceneDesigns/ComplViaduct" + "/ComplViaduct_Thumbnail" + ".png";
// string json_data = File.ReadAllText(str_Parthname);

    Debug.Log("name=="+str_Parthname);
    WWWForm wwform = new WWWForm();
    WWW wwwfile = new WWW(str_Parthname, wwform);
    yield return wwwfile;
    if (wwwfile.error != null)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        //img_display.sprite = LoadNewSprite(str_Parthname);
        Texture2D downloadedImage = new Texture2D(200, 200,TextureFormat.DXT1,false);

        wwwfile.LoadImageIntoTexture(downloadedImage);
        Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,downloadedImage.width,downloadedImage.height);
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(downloadedImage,rect,new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f),100);
        img_display.sprite = sprite;

        //Debug.Log("debug=="+ wwwfile.text);
        //img_display.sprite=
        //txt_displayfoldername.text = wwwfile.text;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Cleanup the code (remove comments) and  explain why this is an answer to the question.