# Creating a WebGL Earth with three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I got a code from web, but this code do not run, I need some HTML code to make it RUN in my browser, someone can help ?

The original code I take from this website (github repository)

http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/09/creating-webgl-earth-with-threejs.html

Github code repository

https://github.com/turban/webgl-earth

Comment: I downloaded the code from github. It appears to work fine. Is your web console showing any errors?

Comment: I executed index.html, but just a light, not the planet, and a black behind

Comment: Hit F12, look for errors, it's probably failing to load resources because you're not serving files off a webserver.

Answer (score 1):

To use WebGL you should run a web server. It will take you about 30 seconds.

[Here's 4-5 options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver)

[**Never disable security in your browser**](https://games.greggman.com/game/dont-disable-web-security/)

Comment: Fair enough, although it took 90 seconds :P But yea, I should downvote myself for that one. Redacted.