# Unable to load texture in WebGl

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl

I am able to load RGB colours but not textures. If it could be some settings problem please prompt me.
This is the screenshot of chrome://flags
[image: chrome://flags]

The HTML code is given :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>WebGL Cube with Texture</title>

<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vshader">
     attribute vec3 coords;
     attribute vec2 texCoords;
     uniform vec3 normal;
     uniform mat4 modelview;
     uniform mat4 projection;
     uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
     varying vec3 vNormal;
     varying vec2 vTexCoords;
     void main() {
        vec4 coords = vec4(coords,1.0);
        vec4 transformedVertex = modelview * coords;
        vNormal = normalMatrix * normal;
        vTexCoords = texCoords;
        gl_Position = projection * transformedVertex;
     }
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fshader">
     precision mediump float;
     uniform bool textured;
     uniform sampler2D sampler;
     varying vec3 vNormal;
     varying vec2 vTexCoords;
     uniform vec4 color;
     void main() {
         if (textured) {
              vec4 color = texture2D(sampler, vTexCoords);
              vec3 unitNormal = normalize(vNormal);
              float multiplier = abs(unitNormal.z);
              gl_FragColor = vec4( multiplier*color.r, multiplier*color.g, multiplier*color.b, color.a );
          }
         else {
              gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // use basic white when texture's not there.
         }
     }
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="simple-rotator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

"use strict";

var gl;   // The webgl context.

var aCoords;           // Location of the coords attribute variable in the shader program.
var aCoordsBuffer;     // Buffer to hold coords.
var aTexCoords;        // Location of the texCoords attribute variable in the shader program.
var aTexCoordsBuffer;  // Buffer to hold texCoords.
var uProjection;       // Location of the projection uniform matrix in the shader program.
var uModelview;        // Location of the modelview unifirm matrix in the shader program.
var uNormal;           // Location of the normal uniform in the shader program.
var uColor;            // Location of the color uniform in the shader program, used only for axes.
var uTextured;         // Location of the textured uniform in the shader program.
var uSampler;          // Location of the sampler in the shader program.
var uNormalMatrix;     // Location of the normalMatrix uniform matrix in the shader program.

var projection = mat4.create();   // projection matrix
var modelview = mat4.create();    // modelview matrix
var normalMatrix = mat3.create(); // matrix, derived from modelview matrix, for transforming normal vectors

var rotator;   // A SimpleRotator object to enable rotation by mouse dragging.

var textureID = null;  // Texture object, to be created after image has loaded.


/* Draws a colored cube, along with a set of coordinate axes.
 * (Note that the use of the above drawPrimitive function is not an efficient
 * way to draw with WebGL.  Here, the geometry is so simple that it doesn't matter.)
 */
function draw() { 
    gl.clearColor(0,0,0,1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (document.getElementById("persproj").checked) {
         mat4.perspective(projection, Math.PI/4, 1, 2, 10);
    }
    else {
         mat4.ortho(projection,-2.5, 2.5, -2.5, 2.5, 2, 10);
    }
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uProjection, false, projection );


    var modelview = rotator.getViewMatrix();
    var saveModelview = mat4.clone(modelview);

    if (textureID) {
         gl.uniform1i( uTextured, 1 );       // Tell shader to use texture and lighting.
         gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureID);     // Which texture should be used.
         gl.uniform1i(uSampler, 0);     // Set sampler in shadre to use texture unit zero.
    }
    else {
         gl.uniform1i( uTextured, 0 );  // Cube will appear in plain white.
    }

    drawFace(modelview)  // front face of the cube
    mat4.rotateY(modelview,modelview,Math.PI/2);  //right face
    drawFace(modelview)  // front face
    mat4.rotateY(modelview,modelview,Math.PI/2);  //back face
    drawFace(modelview)  // front face
    mat4.rotateY(modelview,modelview,Math.PI/2);  //left face
    drawFace(modelview)  // front face
    modelview = mat4.clone(saveModelview);
    mat4.rotateX(modelview,modelview,Math.PI/2);
    drawFace(modelview)  // top face
    mat4.rotateX(modelview,modelview,Math.PI);
    drawFace(modelview)  // bottom face

 }

/**
 * Draws the front face of the cube, subject to a modelview transform.
 */
function drawFace(modelview) {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uModelview, false, modelview );
    mat3.normalFromMat4(normalMatrix, modelview);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(uNormalMatrix, false, normalMatrix);
    gl.uniform3f(uNormal, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);  // front face
}

/**
 * Loads data for the front face of the cube into VBOs.
 */
function createFace() {
     var vertices = [ -1,-1,1, 1,-1,1, 1,1,1, -1,1,1 ];
     var texCoords = [ 0,0, 2,0, 2,2, 0,2 ];
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aCoords);
     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,aCoordsBuffer);
     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
     gl.vertexAttribPointer(aCoords, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aTexCoords);
     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,aTexCoordsBuffer);
     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(texCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
     gl.vertexAttribPointer(aTexCoords, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
}

/**
 * Load an image from the URL "textures/bridk001.jpg".  The image is loade
 * asynchronously.  When the 
 */
function loadTexture() {
     var img = new Image();
     img.onload = function() {
           var id = gl.createTexture();
           gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,id);
           gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
           gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
           gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT);
           gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT);
           textureID = id;
           draw();
     }
     img.src = "./skin.jpg";
}


/* Creates a program for use in the WebGL context gl, and returns the
 * identifier for that program.  If an error occurs while compiling or
 * linking the program, an exception of type String is thrown.  The error
 * string contains the compilation or linking error.  If no error occurs,
 * the program identifier is the return value of the function.
 */
function createProgram(gl, vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource) {
   var vsh = gl.createShader( gl.VERTEX_SHADER );
   gl.shaderSource(vsh,vertexShaderSource);
   gl.compileShader(vsh);
   if ( ! gl.getShaderParameter(vsh, gl.COMPILE_STATUS) ) {
      throw "Error in vertex shader:  " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vsh);
   }
   var fsh = gl.createShader( gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER );
   gl.shaderSource(fsh, fragmentShaderSource);
   gl.compileShader(fsh);
   if ( ! gl.getShaderParameter(fsh, gl.COMPILE_STATUS) ) {
      throw "Error in fragment shader:  " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fsh);
   }
   var prog = gl.createProgram();
   gl.attachShader(prog,vsh);
   gl.attachShader(prog, fsh);
   gl.linkProgram(prog);
   if ( ! gl.getProgramParameter( prog, gl.LINK_STATUS) ) {
      throw "Link error in program:  " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(prog);
   }
   return prog;
}


/* Gets the text content of an HTML element.  This is used
 * to get the shader source from the script elements that contain
 * it.  The parameter should be the id of the script element.
 */
function getTextContent( elementID ) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var fsource = "";
    var node = element.firstChild;
    var str = "";
    while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) // this is a text node
            str += node.textContent;
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return str;
}


/**
 * Initializes the WebGL program including the relevant global variables
 * and the WebGL state.  Creates a SimpleView3D object for viewing the
 * cube and installs a mouse handler that lets the user rotate the cube.
 */
function init() {
   try {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
        gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
        if ( ! gl ) {
            gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        }
        if ( ! gl ) {
            throw "Could not create WebGL context.";
        }
        var vertexShaderSource = getTextContent("vshader"); 
        var fragmentShaderSource = getTextContent("fshader");
        var prog = createProgram(gl,vertexShaderSource,fragmentShaderSource);
        gl.useProgram(prog);
        aCoords =  gl.getAttribLocation(prog, "coords");
        aTexCoords = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, "texCoords");
        uModelview = gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "modelview");
        uProjection = gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "projection");
        uSampler =  gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "sampler");
        uNormal =  gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "normal");
        uColor =  gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "color");
        uTextured =  gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "textured");
        uNormalMatrix =  gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "normalMatrix");
        aCoordsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        aTexCoordsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);  // no need to draw back faces
        document.getElementById("persproj").checked = true;
        rotator = new SimpleRotator(canvas,draw);
        rotator.setView( [2,2,5], [0,1,0], 6 );
   }
   catch (e) {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =
           "Could not initialize WebGL: " + e;
      return;
   }
   createFace();
   loadTexture();
   draw();
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()" style="background-color:#DDD">

<h2>A Cube With a Brick Texture</h2>

<p id=message>Drag the mouse on the canvas to rotate the view.</p>

<p>
  <input type="radio" name="projectionType" id="persproj" value="perspective" onchange="draw()">
      <label for="persproj">Perspective projection</label>
  <input type="radio" name="projectionType" id="orthproj" value="orthogonal" onchange="draw()" style="margin-left:1cm">
      <label for="orthproj">Orthogonal projection</label>
  <button onclick="rotator.setView( [2,2,5], [0,1,0], 6 ); draw()" style="margin-left:1cm">Reset View</button>
</p>

<noscript><hr><h3>This page requires Javascript and a web browser that supports WebGL</h3><hr></noscript>

<div>
   <canvas width=600 height=600 id="glcanvas" style="background-color:red"></canvas>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

All i get as an output is [image: Cube but no texture]
The other functions are loading fine. The file paths are correct.

Comment: What messages are in your JavaScript console? What size is your image?

Comment: @gman 
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at file:///home/mayankmodi/COURSES/graphics/Assignment3/mayanksgame/texturecrate/textures/brick001.jpg may not be loaded.
    at HTMLImageElement.img.onload (file:///home/mayankmodi/COURSES/graphics/Assignment3/mayanksgame/texturecrate/cube-with-texture.html:155:15)

Comment: Place the image in your webserver folder and use the URL path. If webserver hosting your image is on localhost, then http://localhost:<port>/<path to image>/<name of image>

Comment: See [how to setup WebGL](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/webgl/2605/getting-started-with-webgl/8648/installation-or-setup#t=201703030532405420999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you need to run a simple web server for WebGL dev. It should take you about 2 minutes to get setup

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver)

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the minification and magnification parameters for the texture object.
eg:
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

Use the appropriate value for min and mag filter, based on your project requirement.

Comment: could you please explain the diffference between
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
and 
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT);

Comment: TEXTURE_WRAP_T and TEXTURE_WRAP_S define the wrapping behaviour for texture.
TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, and TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER define the filtering behaviour for texture (i.e. how to do minification and magnification)