# Can JavaScript read the contents of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible for JavaScript to read the contents of an iframe embedded in the same page?

If it is, then the same-origin policy could be bypassed? I know of the XMLHttpRequest; it cannot be used to fetch data from other sites by the same-origin policy, e.g., an HTTP GET-request.

Reading the contents of an iframe would effectively provide the same functionality as (unrestricted) XMLHttpRequest’s fetching resources from arbitrary websites?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I don’t know how I would do it.

Comment: Depends on same-origin policy and whether the `X-Frame-Options` header is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, JavaScript can only look into an iframe from the same domain. So, no, you can't use an iframe get unrestricted cross domain access.

The longer answer is if you wanted to test this yourself, install a simple web server. It will take you < 2 mins. [Here's a bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver)

Edit your /etc/hosts file or C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file and add

```
127.0.0.1  first.com
127.0.0.1  second.com
```

Make a folder with an index.html and an iframe.html. Put some JavaScript in index.html to try to look into iframe.html and also to include iframe.html as an iframe

```
<!-- index.html -->
<iframe src="http://second.com:8080/iframe.html></iframe>
<script>
   const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
   console.log(iframe.contentDocument.body.innerText);
</script>

<!-- iframe.html -->
<div>Hello world</div>
```

Run your server using that folder. In the browser go to 
`http://second.com/8080:index.html`

Open the devtools ([chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/), [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)), look at the console, you should see

```
Hello World
```

This worked because they are both on the same domain.

Now change the URL in your browser to `http://first.com:8080/index.html`

This time you'll see something like

```
VM41:66 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' 
 property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin 
"http://first.com:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at HTMLIFrameElement.contentDocumentDesc.get [as contentDocument]
```

Note: depending on which server you use you'll need to change `8080` above to match the port your server uses.

Comment: Thank you - would you provide a snippet of code that reads into an iframe?

Comment: @Shuzheng What good would a snippet do when what you are trying to do isn't possible? the snippet wouldn't work.