# CEFPython app - How to call JSON file from HTML

Tags: python, html, json, chromium-embedded, cefpython

I'm taking my first steps using CEF. I know some Python so I'm using CEFPython. I'm making a simple app processing some data from a local DB with Python and then writing that data to a JSON file. The goal is to finally show the JSON data nicely using HTML, JS and CSS.

I started modifying the [tutorial.py](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/3649975c1bb9ccb76ef4ca8bb31723c71798385b/examples/tutorial.py) file from the Github repo. First, I putted the HTML code in a variable and I'm reading it this way:

```
    HTML_code = open("test.html", "r").read()
```

I then create a browser:

```
    browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(url=html_to_data_uri(HTML_code),
                                settings = browser_settings)
```

Now, in the header of the HTML, I call the JSON file this way:

```
  <script src="test.json"></script>
```

I can render the website, along with the JSON file, perfectly on Chrome. But with CEFPython, I can't load the JSON file this way. I'm guessing there might be some CORS issues.

I tried modifying the browser and cef.Initialize settings, as suggested on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684075/cefpython-app-with-html-js-files-in-local-filesystem) answer. But these changes seem to have no effect. This is how I tried setting them up:

```
    switches = {
    "disable-web-security": ""
}

browser_settings = {
    "file_access_from_file_urls_allowed": "",
    "universal_access_from_file_urls_allowed": "",
    "web_security_disabled": ""
}

cef.Initialize(settings=settings, switches=switches)
set_global_handler()
HTML_code = open("test.html", "r").read()
browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(url=html_to_data_uri(HTML_code),
                                settings = browser_settings)
```

All files (the python script, the HTML and the JSON) are in the same folder. I'm running it by using "python test.py" from the terminal on that folder. I don't want to call the files by using the full path since this program is gonna be used by other people that will not have the same path.

How can I load the JSON file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading a web page using [data URI protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) and "test.json" using file protocol. It is not allowed to mix protocols. Use either file protocol for both or data uri for both (`<script src="data:text/javascript..."></script>`).