# Load an image for WebGL texture but failed because of CORS

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, webgl

I'm reading a tutorial on WebGL ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL)). In this tutorial, we load a texture locally. However, because of cross-origin issue for WebGL texture, we must add `img.crossOrigin="anonymous"`.

Unfortunatly for me, it invokes onerror event.

Here's the code:

```
const image = new Image();
image.onload = () => {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    console.log("Texture loaded.");
};
image.onerror = () => {
    console.log("Texture error!");
}
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = url;
```

What did I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load images locally [you need to run a server and **NOT** set `image.crossOrigin`](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html)

I recommend you start with [this one](https://greggman.github.io/servez) or one of the many [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver)

Comment: Thanks! I understand I have to run a server locally, not just open the HTML document. As I develop with Visual Studio Code, I use Live Server extension.

Comment: So it's working for you now and you can load your texture?

Comment: Yes, it works! I can see my texture on my model now!