# Serving directories with FastAPI application

Tags: directory, fastapi, serve

I need to serve a directory that contains data, like how Apache serves an index, and I would like to serve it through my FastAPI application.

Is that possible with FastAPI or Starlette?

If not, [Simplehttpserver alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver) suggests Twistd as a python package. Is it possible to have FastAPI redirect to a twistd server at the directory mount?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `StaticFiles` utility:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

Arguments usage is documented on [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/):

- The first `"/"` refers to the path this "sub-application" will be "mounted" on. Kn this case, all paths will be handled by it.
- The `directory="static"` refers to the name of the directory that contains your static files on your local filesystem.
- The `name="static"` gives it a name that can be used internally by FastAPI.

All these parameters can be different than "static", adjust them with the needs and specific details of your own application.

> Note: You will need to install [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles): `pip install aiofiles`