# Failing to load model using tf.loadGraphModel in tfjs

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, firefox, tensorflow.js

I am trying to get a webgl app from this github repo: https://github.com/terryky/tfjs_webgl_app working, but I am running into some issues. I would like to use the full-body blazepose model.

I cloned the repo, and just clicked `index.html`. Firefox shows me a dialog that says: "failed to load model", which is coming from this piece of code in `tfjs_blazepose.js`:

```
init_tfjs_blazepose ()
{
    try {
        let url = "./model/tfjs_model_full_pose_detection_float32/model.json";
        s_detect_model = await tf.loadGraphModel(url);

        let url_landmark = "./model/tfjs_model_full_pose_landmark_39kp_float32/model.json";
        s_landmark_model = await tf.loadGraphModel(url_landmark);
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert ("failed to load model");
        alert (e.message)
    }
```

(`index.html` calls `startWebGL();` in `webgl_main.js`, which in turn contains the line `await init_tfjs_blazepose`)

After that message, Firefox presents me with another window containing the error message: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." Looking at other people experiencing this error, I have not yet been able to find the similarities.

My assumption is that something is going wrong with the tf.loadGraphModel function, resulting in this error message, but I am not sure where to look for the problem.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I am experiencing some problems with the `npm install` command right now, so I do not have tfjs installed. From looking here (https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup) however, I assumed this would not be necessary, since these lines are included in the `index.html` file:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm/dist/tf-backend-wasm.js"></script>
```

I have close to zero experience with js in general, so I have the feeling I am just missing some dependencies or something of that nature which might be obvious to you. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: try running it from [a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver)

Comment: @gman Thanks for the response! I am wondering, would this work, since I am not running this using NodeJS? I feel like this code is supposed to run just in my web browser

Comment: You can't fetch files in the browser from your hard drive which is what `tf.loadGraphModel` is trying to do.

Comment: You can add the files to the website's static resources though, which would allow you to load the model directly from browser