# Playwright - Can't access local files using file:// in an img tag

Tags: node.js, playwright

In node js, I am using playwright to open a browser page, setcontent with some html and then take its screenshot. The html contains an image tag and the src of the img is a local file. In the screenshot I don't see the local image. Is local file access disabled? if so how to enable it? I have used relative and absolute path of the file name. If I use a web address, the image is displayed.
I am using Mac OS.

```
async function screenShot() {
  
     const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.setViewportSize({ width:200, height:200 });
    await page.setContent(`
<html><body>
        <div id="container">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
                <img  src="file:///resources/image.png" />
            </div></body>
            </html>
    `)

    await page.locator("#container").screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });

    // Teardown
    await context.close();
    await browser.close();
}
```

Output Image -

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try pasting the `file://` directly in your browser address bar. You'll likely not be able to access something at all if the browser initiates the request. This is a OS-level security setting. You'd have to go into your system settings and allow the browser access to local files.

Comment: The browser can't read from the file system like this. One option is to run a web server to host the site and serve the image and other static assets. An alternative is to inject the image as base64 into the raw HTML. Could you provide a bit more context regarding your use case? Is the image path fixed or dynamic, for example?

Comment: My default browser is able to open the image using the file:// url. However this does seem to be some security issue. I even tried to launch chromium with args to allow local file access like 
const browser = await chromium.launch({ args: ['--allow-file-access-from-files', '--enable-local-file-accesses'] });
But that did not work either.

Comment: I think opening a web server or using base64 may work. Let me try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser can't read from the file system like this for security reasons. There are [flags to disable it, but I'd use those as a last resort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801287/6243352).

One option is to run a web server to host the site and serve the image and other static assets. This can be done out of the box with Python, or using [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) or the [http-server Node package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12905427/6243352). Many IDEs run servers for you when you launch a web project.

For Python, move your HTML to index.html and run `python3 -m http.server` from the directory with index.html in it, verify the image loads when visiting http://localhost:8000 in your browser, then use `page.goto("http://localhost:8000")` and automate the site as normal.

An alternative is to inject the image as base64 into the raw HTML, bypassing the browser request. Here's a minimal example:

```js
const {chromium} = require("playwright"); // ^1.38.0
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");

let browser;
(async () => {
  const b64 = await fs.readFile("test.png", {encoding: "base64"});
  browser = await chromium.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,${b64}" alt="hello world">
    </body>
    </html>
  `);
  await page.screenshot({path: "test_out.png", fullPage: true});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
```

Comment: encoding image to base64 seems to work well!. thanks.